# How can I undo the (potentially) dangerous fix for npm's EACCESS?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Yesterday I tried installing yarn via npm, however was provided with an EACCES errno -13 message.

I followed [this guide](https://letscodepare.com/blog/npm-resolving-eacces-permissions-denied) that recommended 2 fixes in Terminal:

1. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`
2. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

Whilst they fixed the issue, the comments section of the article indicate this fix is a bit dangerous (I only saw the comments after I had made the changes). How can I undo the 2 changes that I made yesterday so I can find an alternative/safer solution?

Comment: In general, you can't. You've recursively changed permissions on a bunch of files and folders - undoing that would require knowing what all of their permissions were _before_ the change. It's not really about programming, see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/1216137, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48845

Comment: Thanks Jon, could restoring a backup of my MAC to before I made the changes fix the issue?